# Google Cloud Build Push Migrations During Build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Currently, I have my cloudbuild setup to do:

```
- id: "apply migrations"
name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
entrypoint: "bash"
args:
  [
    "-c",
    "/buildstep/execute.sh -i gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME} -s ${PROJECT_ID}:${_REGION}:${_INSTANCE_NAME} -e RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$$RAILS_KEY -- bundle exec rails db:migrate",
  ]
secretEnv: ["RAILS_KEY"]
```

When building, I get the following error during the migration step:

```
Caused by:
Step #3 - "apply migrations": PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Step #3 - "apply migrations":   Is the server running locally and accepting
Step #3 - "apply migrations":   connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

What could cause this error to occur? I am unable to find anything about the subject.

Comment: Where is the DB? In Cloud SQL?

Comment: Yes it is a cloud SQL db

Comment: Is your database publicly accessible? Or have only a private IP?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it is publicly accessible with a public IP

Answer (score 1):

The error is about not being able to connect to the database, it seems that the substitutions are not working correctly, in order to correct it verify that your `.env` files has the correct variables and filled with the information from your instance.

If the file has the information required, try removing the `--substitutions` flag and replace the variables (`${PROJECT_ID}`, `${_SERVICE_NAME}`, `${_INSTANCE_NAME}` and so on) with the correct values directly into your `cloudbuild.yaml` file.